# APIM: The Actor–Partner Interdependence Model

Tags: r, regression, modeling, r-lavaan, apim

Does anyone here have experience with Kenny's APIM analysis, using the web app (https://apimsem.ugent.be/shiny/apim_sem/)? I want to control for two variables (age, gender) simultaneously in my APIM model, by including them both as mixed/within covariates in the model. When I include age everything still works fine, however the program gives me an error when I include gender (dichotomously coded). Can anyone help me?